# What happens to an INSERT during a MySQL backup?

Tags: mysql, database, database-backups

Assuming that a backup takes 15 minutes, what happens to an `INSERT` query during a MySQL backup? Does it end up in the backup? What happens to the new row?

I got asked this question on an interview.

Comment: depends on how the backup works. If its i.e. PHP-powered and just running through every table row by row, the new row is in the backup if the backup has not already passed the previous row. But it really depends on the backup system. Better dont insert while backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mysqldump`, it really depends on the options you use. The `--opt` tag is common (shorthand for a bunch of options) and contains `--lock-tables`, which according to the docs:

> For each dumped database, lock all tables to be dumped before dumping
>   them. The tables are locked with READ LOCAL to permit concurrent
>   inserts in the case of MyISAM tables. For transactional tables such as
>   InnoDB, --single-transaction is a much better option than
>   --lock-tables because it does not need to lock the tables at all.

So if you don't lock at all you can have inconsistent tables. If you use `--lock-tables` you can have inconsistent databases.

It also depends on whether you're using MyISAM or InnoDB.

If you're backing up from a slave, `--lock-all-tables` is a better option.

Generally it's a **bad idea** to lock any of your production databases.

You should also keep in mind backing up from a slave can also be dangerous as well! You have to monitor the slaves replication progress and make sure it doesn't get out of sync. And if the replication slave uses "MIXED" or "STATEMENT" mode the replica itself can be inconsistent from the master, depending on the queries used (check the error logs).

There's also an [option to do a "hot backup" with XtraDB](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/02/24/xtrabackup-open-source-alternative-for-innodb-hot-backup-call-for-ideas/), an improved version of InnoDB.

Some people also do [delayed replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html). There's also a page here on [MySQL backup methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html).

As far as what happens to the inserted row *during* the backup process: If the table is locked an INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE query will hang and eventually timeout if the lock is held too long. The timeout interval depends on the configuration.

I highly recommend reading the [mysqldump documentation](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/02/24/xtrabackup-open-source-alternative-for-innodb-hot-backup-call-for-ideas/) carefully.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the backup can be inconsistent. You can lock your tables to prevent this from happening. If you can't lock the tables you can set up a master-slave replication. The slave can be locked and gets the newest changes after the unlock.

Comment: If it is a production DB that sounds bad. I suppose there should be a backup DB slave for that purposes.

Comment: I was just typing that part :D

Comment: Love this site :p While I'm typing something, other 1-10-100-... users doing the same :p

Comment: Well, this stack is definitly faster than ServerFault.